# Arranging another Riley

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, affix-riddle

My prefix is tricking you
My infix is fruity
My suffix is controlled and uniform
My whole must be set

What am I?

Comment: rot13 V unq "pbafgnoyr," ohg gur zber V guvax nobhg gung, gur yrff frafr vg znxrf :(

Comment: @user that's not it, but you're not *entirely* wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Configuration

My prefix is tricking you

> Con

My infix is fruity

> Fig

My suffix is controlled and uniform

> Ration

My whole must be set

> Configuration (especially familiar for programmers).

Comment: Really nice work :)